# Выполнять суммирование пока условие не выполнится

Tags: c++, математика, while, for, ряды

В сем привет! Помогите решить задача на с++. C клавиатуры вводится числа и записываются в переменные max и Del0. Дан цикл While его нужно выполнять до тех пор  пока |sum - x| < Del0. Внутри цикла находится цикл for который выполняет суммирование. У меня получается бесконечный цикл. Необходимо выполнять суммирование до тех пор пока условие не выполнится и на экран вывести n.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код, который у меня получился:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double sum, Del0, x;
    int n, max;

    n = 1;

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    cout << "Введите max: " << endl;
    cin >> max;

    cout << "Введите De10: " << endl;
    cin >> Del0;

    x = pow(3.14, 2) / 12;

    sum = 0;
    while (abs(sum - x) < Del0) {
        for (n = 1; n <= max; n++) {
            sum = pow((-1), n + 1) * 1 / pow(n, 2);
            cout << "При n = " << n << " сумма равна " << sum << endl;
        }
    } 

    cout << "Количество элементов: " << n << endl;
}
```

Comment: дайте пожалуйста более подробное условие, или же сами исправьте, так как не очень ясна суть задачи

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот примерно что от вас хотят...

```
int main()
{
    double x = 3.14159265358*3.14159265358/12;
    double delta;
    cout << "Введите Delta: " << endl;
    cin >> delta;

    cout << "Ожидаемое количество элементов: " << ceil(1/sqrt(delta)) << endl;

    double sum = 0;
    for(int n = 1, sig = -1; ; ++n)
    {
        sum += double(sig *= -1)/n/n;
        cout << "n = " << setw(8) << n << ":  "
            << setprecision(10) << sum << endl;
        if (abs(sum - x) < delta)
        {
            cout << "Количество элементов: " << n << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. Что-то за сегодня уже вторую простейшую математику исправлять приходится...

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста почему у вас в переменной sum два раза /n /n. У меня вот такой пример: (-1) ^ n + 1 * 1 / n^2

Comment: Чтоб не вызывать `pow(n,2)` - если можно обойтись делением... Можно написать `/(n*n)`.

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению я не уверен, так как условие не очень мне понятно, но если исходить из того, что мы имеем, код у Вас в принципе верный, цикл становится бесконечным по той причине, что переменная **sum - не увеличивается**.

**Решение**:
Исправить: `sum = pow((-1), n + 1) * 1 / pow(n, 2);`

**На**

```
sum +=sum + (pow((-1), n + 1) * 1 / pow(n, 2));
```

Comment: Надеюсь, `pow((-1), n + 1)` - это не всерьез?...

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решилась следующим образом, спасибо.

```
int main()
    {
        double sum, Del0, x;
        int n, max;

        setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

        cout << "Введите max: " << endl;
        cin >> max;

        cout << "Введите De10: " << endl;
        cin >> Del0;

        x = 3, 14 * 3, 14 / 12;

        n = 1;
        sum = 0;
        while (abs(sum - x) < Del0) {
            for (n = 1; n <= max; n++) {
                sum = sum + pow(-1, n + 1) * 1 / pow(n, 2);
                cout << "При n = " << n << " сумма равна " << sum << endl;
            }
        } 

        cout << "Количество элементов: " << n << endl;

    }
```

Comment: Простите уж, ерунду написали. У вас как минимум `x` равно просто 3... Условие `abs(sum - x) < Del0` сразу не выполняется (вряд ли вы берете Del больше 3) - так что ваша программа просто выводит 1 в качестве количества элементов и все... См. https://ideone.com/QrgIA2